# Konvajs: How can I click one node, start moving mouse, but drag another node?

Tags: konvajs

I have two nodes. Is it possible to click one node, begin dragging, but drag another node instead?

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X?" / "Can I do X?" / "Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is you want. Right now, this is a "yes"/"no" question. Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273)

Comment: Do you mean to consider the two nodes as being on the same layer? If so then use a layer and drag that. If you want to use shape #1 as a trackpad and move another shape around based on movement of the mouse inside the trackpad shape then you need to compute the relative movement for shape 2 based on scale and position on the trackpad etc. All possible. Clarify your question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
node1.on('dragstart', () => {
  node1.stopDrag();
  // reset position
  node1.position({
    x: 100,
    y: 100
  })

  // start dragging another shape
  node2.startDrag();
});
```

Also, you may try to use `click` or `mousedown` event instead of `dragstart` (choose what is better for your use case).

Demo: http://jsbin.com/quqekabeci/1/edit?js,output